# Sending an email in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

To send an email I have set the config as follows

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

$this->email->send();
```

My outlook email account smtp is set up as

```
mail.mycompany.com
```

I have got error for sending an email from this account to any other accounts. I forget the error message and I can not replicate it right now on this computer, but look at those config's, do you think it is correct ? (before call function send to send an email I also included the call to its initializer or to load its library for use in the controller contructor already).

Comment: You config looks superb. Whatever your problem is, you should always add the error message otherwise nobody is able to help you if it's not something very obvious.

Comment: You have the SMTP server, username, and password in the config file, right?

Comment: Are you doing all of this by any chance offline in Mamp or Wamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, try to use protocol sendmail

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);
```

If You're using smtp protocol You need to define whats Your smtp params:

```
$config['smtp_host']     
$config['smtp_user']    
$config['smtp_pass']
```

Then

```
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

$this->email->send();

echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```